# Is there a code for repairing the holes left in the roof from removing static box vents?

Tags: roof, vent

I have a two story house and I am having the roofer put the GAF Timberline HDZ shingles on it.  I am also going to go with ridge vents instead of the static box vents that are on the roof now.
Does code require the roofer to plug the holes with wood or metal or are the allowed to just cover with the holes with underlayment and shingles?    Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shingles are heavy and flexible, regardless of code, I don't think that putting underlayment and shingles over a hole would be a very robust job.

Comment: What does your contract with the roofer state?

Comment: IDK what code says, but I would NOT let a roofer cover holes simply with underlay and shingles.

Answer (score 4):

The codes would vary with location but I've never seen a hole just covered with underlayment and shingles. It will usually have some sheet metal covering small holes and plywood, same thickness as the decking, for the larger holes. Sometimes, it's easier to just rip out a full sheet with the hole and replace with a new sheet or go rafter to rafter. Make sure you discuss this with your roofer and it's put in your contract.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.chicago.gov/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/Building%20Code/CodeMemorandumRoofingRequiremensRev.pdf

> Roofing material shall be installed in accordance with the manufacturer's instructions in regards to fasteners, underlayment, **and sheathing**.

> *Roof Replacement* : The process of removing the existing *roof covering*, repairing any damaged substrate including insulation **or sheathing** and installing a new *roof assembly*.

Code is nice and all, but people not falling off or through your roof would be better then weaseling around the semantics of what exactly the scope here is, be it *roof repair* or what it should be: *roof replacement*. I doubt the shingles say they can span gaps of 10"....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're under the IRC, there's [IRC R905.2.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-9-roof-assemblies#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch09_SecR905.2.1),

> Asphalt shingles shall be fastened to solidly sheathed decks.

I'm sure that the definition of "solidly sheathed deck" varies widely from inspector to inspector. I expect that any inspector would reject an 8" hole in the deck as non-conformant.